# How can i use DataTables in jQuery to order column when I'm sending data from ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

```
<script>
    var userdataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "order":[],
        "ajax": {
            url: "purchase_fetch.php",
            type: "POST",
        },


        "pageLength": 10
    });
</script>
```

> the data loads correctly in the table but it sorts incorrectly. can you please help me!
> what could be missing?  I am new to jQuery and ajax. and I haven't found any good tutorials online on DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the datatable "order" parameter in PHP (it's the index of the ordered column and the direction)

```
$orderArray = $_GET['order'];
```

2. Get the datatable "colums" parameter in PHP

```
$columns = $_GET['columns'];
```

3. Match the order index with the column name

```
        if (!empty($orderArray )) {
            $orderDir = $orderArray [0]['dir'];
            $order = $orderArray [0]['column'];
            if (array_key_exists($order , $columns )) {
                $orderBy = $columns [$order ]['data'];
            }
        }
```

4. Change the DB query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable mt 
ORDER BY $orderBy $orderDir ";
```

This is just an exemple, secure the SQL with PDO parameters.
If the datatable column name is not the same as the database column name, you can change it with the datatable "data" options :

```
columns: [{title: "My Datatable Column Name", data: 'my_database_column_name'}]
```

Comment: Thank you,  I will try your suggestions.